# How to export information about the monitor to a csv file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv, inventory, get-wmiobject

I am new to PowerShell and am struggling to write a script to export the `UserFriendlyName` (see the code below) for three monitors. Here is what I have so far:

```
$monitors = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID

Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName wmimonitorid -ComputerName $ComputerName |

foreach {
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        MonitorName = ($monitors.UserFriendlyName -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
        MonitorSerial = ($monitors.serialnumberid -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
    } 
}

$Object | Select MonitorName,MonitorSerial
$Object | Export-Csv -append -force /Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result that I am getting:

```
MonitorName                MonitorSerial                        
-----------                -------------                        
27B1DELL P2717HDELL P2717H GUHJBHA018695YKNFG6CQAGLLYKNFG71KAPTL
```

I would like to have each monitor name and serial number under their own column (`Monitor 1`, `Monitor 2`, `Monitor 3` and the same for serial number) but the values are together. Any help is much appreciated.

I am hoping to have the above incorporated with this:

```
$computerSystem = Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem
$computerBIOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement
$computerOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem
$computerCPU = Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor
$computerHDD = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'"

Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName wmimonitorid -ComputerName $ComputerName | 

foreach {


$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Computer Name" = $computerSystem.Name
    "Operating System" = $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
    "Manufacturer" = $computerSystem.Manufacturer
    "Model" = $computerSystem.Model
    "Serial Number" = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
    "CPU" = $computerCPU.Name
    "HDD Capacity" = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB"
    "RAM" = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
    "User logged In" = $computerSystem.UserName
    } 
}

$Object | Export-Csv -append -force /Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: you can iterate thru the monitor list and build each property with the index number in the prop name. something like `$SysInfoProps.Add("Vid_Monitor_${Index}_Name"` and then use the hashtable to build a PSCustomObject.

Answer (score 0):

Something does not seem right with your code.  You should be adding each monitor to an array or a list.

```
$monitors = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class wmiMonitorID

$allMonitors = @()

Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName wmimonitorid -ComputerName $ComputerName |

foreach {
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
        MonitorName = ($monitors.UserFriendlyName -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
        MonitorSerial = ($monitors.serialnumberid -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
    } 

    $allMonitors += $Object
}

$allMonitors | Select MonitorName,MonitorSerial
$allMonitors | Export-Csv -append -force /Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
```